# OS X Lion, Moutain Lion, Mavericks, Yosemite: deep sleep on low battery leads to crash

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I'm having an issue on my Mac since I installed Lion and now Mountain Lion (I thought that the Lion problem could be because I've put an SSD in my Mac and did not make a fresh install but a carbon copy to the new disk, but it still happens with Mountain Lion with a format/fresh install).

What is happening to me is that, when I put my Mac to sleep and the battery dies, it does not restore the state like a normal sleep that it did when I was on Snow Leopard. Now when the battery dies, the computer restarts: I need to put my password and the programs open again but some of them lose the previous state (like VLC, Chrome has the "restore" option, etc.) it is exactly like a restart with the option "Reopen windows when logging back in" selected.

Is this normal or should it happen like in Snow Leopard?

If this is the normal behavior, I will turn off Deep Sleep since the Mac takes less time to sleep with it off. (I think that the more time is because it is storing the state of the RAM on the disk so it could recover when the battery goes off which it doesn't do properly!)

```
$ pmset -g | grep hibernatemode
 hibernatemode        3
```

Comment: The problem is fully reproductible on Mavericks, Yosemite which I run on MacBook Pro. [return] I can't try it on Sierra and High Sierra which I run on iMacs.

Answer (score 1):

Does you SSD use a SandForce controller?  SandForce controllers seem to have some serious issues related to battery and sleep/hibernate activities, and you might (I repeat might) be seeing some of these problems coming up:

[SandForce controller problems](http://communities.intel.com/thread/33953)

If you have a SandForce controller you might want to change SSD altogether, based on the info provided by the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am having very same issue, not always by the way. It just looks like remaining battery is not enough in order to complete writing to disk.
I am coming from Lion.

Previously after hibernation my Mac status was just restored fine from disk.

Sadly it looks like there is no way to change haltlevel for battery, just like you can do with UPS.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your battery is either in need of calibration or it needs to be replaced due to being unable to sustain power when the system expects it to.

Comment: I've calibrated it (use all the battery and leave the mac for 5+ hours without energy) and the battery is still at 94% of health... =/

Comment: Perhaps you have a failing cell in your battery. How old is it?

Comment: 2 years and some months. yesterday I've used it until the mac shutdown and it did not suspended at 10%, it went until 0%, I've only put it to charge now. I'm testing it again

Answer (score -2):

It is completely normal. When battery level reaches reserve (less than 10%), it hibernates which saves RAM state onto HDD as you've mentioned in the question.

If you still want to disable that behaviour run this in the Terminal:

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0
```

and it will be disabled. You can change it back by replacing 0 with 3 (the default).

Comment: it would be normal if when I turned on the mac it restored the state it was before (like when it is on RAM), That is actually my question, if it was normal to not restore...